# Dynamically update queries as new database comes into existence

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Platform:  SQL Server 2008
Language: TSQL

I have a number of queries that currently take the general form of (for simplicity sake)

```
-- Sample begin results
SELECT * from DB01.dbo.table UNION ALL
SELECT * from DB02.dbo.table UNION ALL --many other databases follow with same syntax
```

How can I modify these queries such that, when a new database comes into existence (named, say DB39C), I ensure that my queries already includes those new records?

```
--Sample end results
SELECT * from DB01.dbo.table UNION ALL
SELECT * from DB02.dbo.table UNION ALL
SELECT * from DB39C.dbo.table -- this was created as soon as a new database came into existence
```

I am looking to make sure programmatically, that this happens without my awareness as new databases are added quite regularly and I need the queries I rely on to keep pace.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at using something like

```
SELECT name AS DATABASENAME
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
```

and creating dynamic queries

[sys.databases (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx)

Comment: As of SQL Server 2005, you should stop using the "old" `sysobjects` and `sysdatabases` catalog views. Instead, use the **new** views in the `sys` schema - `sys.databases` is your friend!